# React Native react-native-svg showing error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, svg

I am trying to use `svg` in `react native`, I installed `react-native-svg`, but it is show `error`, below the code with error.

```
import { SvgUri } from 'react-native-svg';


<SvgUri width="100%" height="100%" uri="http://thenewcode.com/assets/images/thumbnails/homer-simpson.svg"/>
```

Please check the `erro`r in attached image

[image: Link to the error image]

Answer (score 0):

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { SvgCssUri } from 'react-native-svg';
 
export default () => (
  <SvgCssUri
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    uri="http://thenewcode.com/assets/svg/accessibility.svg"
  />
);
```